# Movable container on the top of my application in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jdialog, jinternalframe

I'm trying to make a movable container (Panel or Frame) in my application in Java Swing on button click.

I've tried using `JDialog`, but I interfere with other `JDialog`s in my application. I've tried `JInternal` Frame, which is immovable.

```
iconButton = new JButton(Icons.birdIcon);
iconButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JDialog p= new JDialog();
        p.setSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        p.setBackground(Color.black);
        ComponentMover cm = new ComponentMover();
        cm.registerComponent(p);
        threeDPanel.add(p);
    }
});
```

How should I proceed if I want a panel on top of the frame with a button click, which will be movable ?

Comment: *I've tried using Jdialog* - sound like the correct approach to me, *but i interfere with other Jdialogs in my application* - don't know what that means.

Comment: So When i make Jdialog popup with the button click. If i try to open any other jdialog in my application, the whole application freeze.I am looking to make a panel full of icons that can be used throughout the application.I will add image for reference.

Comment: There are two types of dialogs - modal or non-modal. Modal means you can't click on the parent JFrame (or any other dialog) until you close the dialog. Non-modal means you can have multiple dialogs open and interact with the dialog or the frame.

Comment: Thank you so much @camickr that solves my issue :) :)